# Passing buffer as Uint8Array without null bytes

Tags: javascript, node.js, tesseract

I'm trying to pass image data from [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp) image object to Tesserract (ocr lib) via buffer:

```js
image.getBufferAsync('image/png').then((buffer) => {
  // Buffer here is <Buffer 12 34 56 ...
  const worker = new TesseractWorker();
  worker.recognize(buffer)
      .then((result) => { console.log('result', result.text); });

});
```

Which throws an error from Teserract saying that it wants Uint8Array and not buffer

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received <Buffer 89 50 4e 47...
```

So I try to convert buffer to Uint8Array:

```
buffer = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

But I get another error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_VALUE]: The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received Uint8Array [
  137,
  80,
  ...
```

Where is a mistake?

---

If I save image file to disc and then read its path via Teserract - it works, so the problem shouldn't be the image.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that, in Node JS, the `img` parameter should be a path to a local image.

> On a browser, an image can be:
>
> - an img, video, or canvas element
> - a File object (from a file )
> - a path or URL to an accessible image
>
> In Node.js, an image can be
>
> - a path to a local image

https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/blob/master/docs/image-format.md

This means the library would like to do its own reading of the file rather than being given a stream of bytes for analysis.

Answer (score -1):

The below worked for me.  Think we might be on different versions of tesseract (v.3.05), but don't think it changes much.

```
    var Jimp = require('jimp');
    var Tesseract = require('tesseract.js');
    var file = 'YourFile.png';  // Or .jpg etc...

    Jimp.read(file, async (err, image) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        //Do your Jimp stuff here to 'image' then...

        const buffer = await image.getBufferAsync(Jimp.AUTO);

        //Above line creates a buffer using Jimp.AUTO (the  
        //original file format from your variable 'file')

        Tesseract.recognize(buffer,'eng')
            .then(data => {
             console.log(data)
            })
     })
```